# Why does my flash have lower power in automatic than in manual?

Tags: flash, exposure, sony, sony-nex

I have a Sony HVL-43AM flash. I've found that when I'm in automatic mode, when I dial the flash exposure compensation to -2EV I was able to get a much weaker flash than if I went manual with the flash and set it to minimum power (1/128). Why is this?